# Unchecking a checkbox in react from several checkbox groups (I'm using React hooks)

Tags: reactjs

I have several checkboxes running in several checkbox groups. I can't figure out how to uncheck (thus changing the state) on a particular checkbox. FOr some reason I can't reach `e.target.checked`.

```
  <Checkbox
      size="small"
      name={item}
      value={item}
      checked={checkboxvalues.includes(item)}
      onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
  />
```

and my function

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
   const check = e.target.checked;
   setChecked(!check);
};
```

I made a working sample of the component in [**this sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sunset-81gyy3?file=/components/Selectors.js:4616-4715).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create handleOnChange function specific to each group. I have created one for Genre checkbox group in similar way you can create for other groups.

Here is handler function.

```
const handleOnChangeGenre = (e) => {
    let newValArr = [];
    if (e.target.checked) {
      newValArr = [...state.pillarGenre.split(","), e.target.value];
    } else {
      newValArr = state.pillarGenre
        .split(",")
        .filter((theGenre) => theGenre.trim() !== e.target.value);
    }
    setState({ ...state, pillarGenre: newValArr.join(",") });
  };
```

pass this function as handleOnChange prop to CustomCheckboxGroup as below.

```
<CustomCheckboxGroup
          checkboxdata={genres}
          checkboxvalues={state.pillarGenre}
          value={state.pillarGenre}
          sectionlabel="Genre"
          onToggleChange={handleGenreSwitch}
          togglechecked={genreswitch}
          handleOnChange={handleOnChangeGenre}
        />
```

comment your handleOnChange function for testing.

check complete working solution here in sandbox -
[complete code](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-tereshkova-mj9hvi?file=/components/Selectors.js)

Comment: After testing yours and tao's answer, yours ended up being the most straightforward with the code I already have done. I'm extrmely appreciative of both of you. I do have one small issue with your answer. Because `"English, Non-English"` both contain the word English, they get treated the same way, Same with `"HBO, HBO Max"`, Is there anyway, that I can make the difference between them more explicit?

Comment: Above problem can resolve by changing checked prop value logic from string search to array search as below.                                                                                          <Checkbox
                        size="small"
                        name={item}
                        value={item}
                        checked={checkboxvalues
                          .split(",")
                          .find((val) => val.trim() === item.trim())}
                        onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                      />

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-pateu-flwqvp?file=/components/Selectors.js

I've abstracted the selection logic into a `useSelection()` custom hook, which means current selection is to be found in `store[key].selected`, where `key` can be any of `selectors`'s keys.

`items`, `selected`, `setSelected` and `sectionLabel` from each `useSelection()` call are stored into `store[key]` and spread onto a `<CustomCheckboxGroup />` component.

The relevant bit is the `handleCheck` function inside that component, which sets the new selection based on the previous selection's value: if the current `item` is contained in the previous `selected` value, it gets removed. Otherwise, it gets added.

---

**A more verbose explanation (the *why*)**

Looking closer at your code, it appears you're confused about how the checkbox components function in React.

The `checked` property of the `input` is controlled by a state `boolean`. Generic example:

```js
const Checkbox = ({ label }) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  return (
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
      />
      <span>{label}</span>
    </label>
  )
}
```

On every render, the `checked` value of the `<input />` is set according to current value of `checked` state. When the input's `checked` changes (on user interaction) the state doesn't update automatically. But the `onChange` event is triggered and we use it to update the state to the negative value of the state's previous value.

---

When dealing with a `<CheckboxList />` component, *we **can't** serve a single boolean to control **all** checkboxes*, we need *one boolean for **each** of the checkboxes* being rendered. So we create a `selected` array and set the `checked` value of each `<input />` to the value of `selected.includes(item)` (which returns a `boolean`).

For this to work, we need to update the value of `selected` array in every `onChange` event. We check if the `item` is contained in the previous version of `selected`. If it's there, we filter it out. If not, we add it:

```js
const CheckboxList = ({ items }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])
  const onChecked = (item) =>
    setSelected((prev) =>
      prev.includes(item)
        ? prev.filter((val) => val !== item)
        : [...prev, item]
    )

  return items.map((item) => (
    <label key={item}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={selected.includes(item)}
        onChange={() => onChecked(item)}
      />
      <span>{item}</span>
    </label>
  ))
}
```

Hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: This is incredibly clean! I love it, but I lost the ability to reshape my state, see the setters I'm assigning to each component? How would I manage those states in your code?

Comment: @Lotus, you can still use `useEffect()` to set whatever you want. You just need to place the appropriate dependencies in the deps array (e.g: `store.genres.selected` to watch `genres` changes, or `store.contentTypes.selected`, etc...). That's where you'll find the currently selected items, for each of the store keys.

Comment: I don't quite follow your state's business logic, but I updated my sandbox with an example on how you could set it up. Update it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks. It works better now, it does update the state as I click on and off on the checkboxes, but it doesn't seem to read onload, as it load with everything marked regardless. But that's ok. I'll take it from here. I do appreciate it

Comment: It loads with everything marked because I instantiate the `selected` with `items` in the `useSelector` hook. If you want to instantiate with a particular value, pass it to the `useSelector` as an argument (e.g: `current`) and use it as `const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(current)`. If the current selection value is a string, you'll have to turn it into an array of strings before passing it: `current: currentValue.split(', ')`.

Comment: If you run into any blockers, create a new fork and let me have a look. Advice: don't modify the sandbox linked in the question, as you'll hinder anyone else's ability to understand and answer the question, as well as the question's utility to other users with a similar issue.

Comment: I appreciate the help, Basically, the way your code is setup it's populating all checkboxes and made all true. Which is partly correct, because all of the checkboxes must show up, but they arent always all "true", for ex, if a user selects only the drama movies, the screen should load with only dram selected in genres, and moveis selected in contentType. (this selection happens in a dropdown that I didn't add in the question for brevity because it fires up a get request with those params to get a response that includes only that piece of data). I hope that makes sense

Comment: I added a fork in which I included a sample of what the API looks like when it comes back `https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-ioana-ugqbug`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251841/discussion-between-tao-and-lotusms).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it, it's to save selected checkboxes into a state array, so to check or uncheck it you just filter this state array based on checkbox value property that need to be unique.

Try to use array.some() on checkbox property checked. To remove it it's just filter the checkboxes setted up in the state array that are different from that single checkbox value.

Comment: Can you show me in code? You’re welcomed to use the link I provided for the sandbox.